Making \includegraphics interact with \graphicspath in AUCTeX
Can I make \includegraphics aware of \graphicspath arguments when prompted for a graphics file?
I have
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images}}

in the preamble. With C-c C-m \includegraphics I am prompted for a filename. I want to get a choice only between files in ./images, and choosing, say, img01.png from the file list, I want \includegraphics{img01} inserted.  Setting the variable  LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file to 'LaTeX-includegraphics-read-file-relative I get a choice of graphics files in all subdirectories, and the entire file path images/img01 is inserted. So this not quite what I want.

From epslatex.pdf:

13.3 Graphics Search Path
By default, LATEX looks for graphics files in any directory on the TEX search path. In addition to these
directories, LATEX also looks in any directories specified in the
\graphicspath command. For example,
\graphicspath{{dir1/}{dir2/}}
tells LATEX to also look for graphics files in dir1/ and dir2/. [...]
It is important to note that the file-searching associated with
\graphicspath directories is much slower than that associated with
TEXINPUTS directories. Furthermore, each file search done in a
\graphicspath directory consumes additional pool space (see Section
13.4 on Page 41).
Due to these inefficiencies, use of \graphicspath is generally discouraged. Instead, it is usually better to specify
subdirectories by modifying the TEX search path (see Section 13.1 on
Page 39).

I think the limitation above is the main reason why parsing the \graphicspath isn't implemented in AUCTeX (from looking at the comments in tex-style.el).
Maybe you can follow the advice above and adjust the TEXINPUTS directories which should work within AUCTeX OOTB.

Thanks, that makes perfect sense
